# Convert from Queue to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, casting

I want to change a queue containing numbers and operators into an ArrayList.
I am coding in Java.

Currently my Queue is defined as follows:

```
Queue outputQueue = new LinkedList();
```

The queue currently contains the following data:

```
[1, 9, 3, /, 4, 3, -, 2, /, *, +]
```

I wish to do this mainly so i can use RPN to calculate the result of the calculation.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: I don't understand why you need it to be an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Ummm, a simple while loop would do?

Answer (score 8):

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(outputQueue);
```

Answer (score 5):

Do like this

```
List list = new ArrayList(outputQueue);
```

Answer (score 3):

While the other answers are the correct way to create an `ArrayList`.  You could simply cast it to a `List`.  This would leave the same underlying data structure (`LinkedList`) but you can use it as a List then.

```
Queue outputQueue = new LinkedList();
List list = (List)outputQueue;
```

Weather or not this is a better way to do what you need depends on how you are using the List.  You have to decide if the cost of create a new `ArrayList` is worth the the potential speed increase in accessing your data. Take a look at [When to use LinkedList<> over ArrayList<>?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/322742/1426079).

Answer (score 2):

Code like this

```
Queue outputQueue = new LinkedList();
outputQueue.add("1");
outputQueue.add("9");
outputQueue.add("3");
outputQueue.add("/");
outputQueue.add("4");
outputQueue.add("3");
outputQueue.add("-");
outputQueue.add("2");
outputQueue.add("*");
outputQueue.add("+");
ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList(outputQueue);
```