# How to collect the elements of a Stream into a Queue?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, queue, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
Queue<Reward> possibleRewards = 
    Stream.of(Reward.values())
          .flatMap(reward -> IntStream.range(0, reward.getOccurencies()).mapToObj(i -> reward))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As you can see, I need to collect the elements of the `Stream` into a `Queue`, not a `List`. However, there's no `Collectors.toQueue()` method. How can I collect the elements into a `Queue`?

Comment: What stops you from instantiating the queue from the resulting list anyway? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708358/convert-from-queue-to-arraylist

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522341/collection-to-stream-to-a-new-collection

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.toCollection()`, which lets you choose whatever `Collection` implementation you wish to produce:

```
Queue<Reward> possibleRewards = 
    Stream.of(Reward.values())
          .flatMap(reward -> IntStream.range(0, reward.getOccurencies()).mapToObj(i -> reward))
          .collect(Collectors.toCollection(PriorityQueue::new)); // use whatever Queue 
                                                                 // implementation you want
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Queue<Reward> possibleRewards = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(); //Or whichever type of queue you would like
possibleRewards.addAll(Stream.of(Reward.values())
    .flatMap(reward -> IntStream.range(0, reward.getOccurencies()).mapToObj(i -> reward))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```