# Convert queue into long array?

Tags: java, arrays, list, queue

I have a `Queue` which I want to convert into `long[]` and pass it to my method which calculate percentiles.

```
private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Long> holder = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
```

I am using `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` because I am inserting latencies which are in milliseconds from multithread application into my above `holder` queue so I wanted to be thread safe.

Now my question is how can I convert `holder` queue into `long[]` long array so that I can pass it to my below method? Is there any way to do that?

```
  public static long[] percentiles(long[] latencies, double... percentiles) {
    Arrays.sort(latencies, 0, latencies.length);
    long[] values = new long[percentiles.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < percentiles.length; i++) {
      int index = (int) (percentiles[i] * latencies.length);
      values[i] = latencies[index];
    }
    return values;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: May this question be a duplicate of this?
[Convert a Queue to ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708358/convert-from-queue-to-arraylist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [ConcurrentLinkedQueue#toArray(T[] a)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#toArray(T[])) will get you 90% of the way there:

```
Long[] longs = holder.toArray(new Long[0]);
```

Converting `Long[]` to `long[]` left as exercise to student. ;-)